# Understanding the Use% column of the df command output

Tags: df

Below is an output of df command

```
# df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used     Available Use%  Mounted on
/dev/sda2         122835  26732     89550     23%   /boot
```

It seems that

```
Used =  1K-blocks - Available - Reserved
```

where Reserved can be retrieved using the below command:

> `tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | egrep "Block size:|Reserved block count"`

```
Reserved block count:     6553
Block size:               1024
```

But cannot understand how Use% is calculated.
Shouldn't be it just:

```
 (Used / 1K-blocks) * 100
```

Or

```
(1K-blocks - Available)/(1K-blocks) * 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Use%" is calculated this way:

```
Used / ( Used + Available ) * 100 %
```